# swagger UI passing headers to API try out calls programmatically

Tags: swagger-ui

All our services require an authentication token to be passed in a header. I know the correct way to go about that would be to use oauth but its not yet supported for our use case.

What I want to do is to get the token once by making a call to authentication service and then set it for all try out requests from swagger UI index page. There is enough documentation on how to pass a custom header to swagger API calls (the calls to get API info) but I couldn't find anything which would set a custom header for all the "try out" calls.

I will appreciate any advise.

Thanks,
Jas